# Select Descendants of particular element

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm trying to run a LINQ - XML query to get the descendants of a particular XML File.

I've got multiple  elements from which I need to select a result with a particular tracking number and display the event history.

The XML File:

```
    <result>
      <trackingnumber>31343</trackingnumber>
      <source>post</source>
      <eventhistory>
        <eventhistory>
          <eventdate>21/10/11</eventdate>
          <eventtime>06.48 PM</eventtime>
          <location>tauranga</location>
        </eventhistory>
        <eventhistory>
          <eventdate>21/10/11</eventdate>
          <eventtime>06.48 PM</eventtime>
          <location>tauranga</location>
        </eventhistory>
        <eventhistory>
          <eventdate>21/10/11</eventdate>
          <eventtime>06.48 PM</eventtime>
          <location>tauranga</location>
        </eventhistory>
      </eventhistory>
    </result>
```

My current code:

```
    IEnumerable<TrackData> data = from info in xdoc.Descendants("eventhistory")
                                  where     info.Element("eventtime") != null &&
                                            info.Parent.Element("trackingnumber").Value == TrackingNumber
                                  select

                                      new TrackData()
                                      {
                                          EventTime = (string)info.Element("eventtime") ?? "No Time Info",
                                          EventDate = (string)info.Element("eventdate") ?? "No Date Info"


                                      };
```

Where am I going wrong? I kind of understand that I probobly shouldn't be finding the descendants first then checking if the other element has the correct tracking number in it, but am unsure how I would fix it.

Also, is there a LINQ XML bible of some kind that would give me a good guide to this in the future? I seem to be getting stuck on LINQ XML all the time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your where condition need to be change, since you have parent `eventhistory` and `trackingnumber` is Element of `result` element you need to call the `Parent` twice

```
where     info.Element("eventtime") != null &&
          info.Parent.Parent.Element("trackingnumber").Value == TrackingNumber
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly... but is there a better way to do it rather than having the tracking number in the where statement?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `info.Parent.Parent.Element("trackingnumber")` and you should have a separate name for the wrapper of eventhistory, which is the parent. Result is the parent of EventHistories and has the element TrackingNumber

```
<eventhistories>
        <eventhistory>
          <eventdate>21/10/11</eventdate>
          <eventtime>06.48 PM</eventtime>
          <location>tauranga</location>
        </eventhistory>
        <eventhistory>
      <eventdate>21/10/11</eventdate>
      <eventtime>06.48 PM</eventtime>
      <location>tauranga</location>
    </eventhistory>
    <eventhistory>
      <eventdate>21/10/11</eventdate>
      <eventtime>06.48 PM</eventtime>
      <location>tauranga</location>
    </eventhistory>
 </eventhistories>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the data feed so can't change the XML....

But thanks! Didn't realise I needed two parents. Just realised why!